# @Autowired field always null in the test, what am I missing?

Tags: java, spring, testng, autowired

Test properties:

```
package com.sandbox.test;

import lombok.Getter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:new-test.properties")
public class TestProperties {
    @Getter
    @Value("${homepage.url}")
    private String homePageUrl;
}
```

Configuration:

```
package com.sandbox.test;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.sandbox"})
public class SpringContext {
}
```

Content of `new-test.properties` file that is located in /src/test/resources:

```
homepage.url=https://tst.mysite.com
```

And 2 tests in `MyTest` class, first one - doesn't work, second - works fine:

```
package com.sandbox.test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringContext.class})
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestProperties testProperties;

    @Test
    public void thisDoesntWork() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(testProperties);
        System.out.println(testProperties.getHomePageUrl());
    }

    @Test
    public void thisWorks() {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringContext.class);
        TestProperties testProps = appContext.getBean(TestProperties.class);

        Assert.assertNotNull(testProps);
        System.out.println(testProps.getHomePageUrl());
    }
}
```

The goal is to autowire `testProperties` field in `MyTest` class **without using xml**. But currently it's `null`. `@Component` and `@ComponentScan` annotations are in place, but what am I missing?..

Comment: What is "BaseTest"? You need to run your UnitTest by a SpringRunner. JUnit will not do a spring scan out of the box.

Comment: "BaseTest" is empty, nothing happens there, I've edited the question. I am using TestNG, not JUnit

Comment: TestNG or JUnit, does not matter. Search for "how to test spring application".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-ctx-management) of Spring. Probably your test needs to extend 
 **AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests** to have access to the **ApplicationContext** automatically and make autowire work.